# Translating a Neo4j cypher query into orientdb / gremlin (in java)

Tags: java, neo4j, orientdb, gremlin

I have a Neo4j cypher query that looks like this:

> MATCH
>   (b:VertexType1)-[e1]-(a:VertexType2)-[e2]-(c:VertexType1)-[e3]-(d)

What this translates to in english (I think) is:

"Find me a chain of vertices 'b','a','c','d' of type 'VertexType1', 'VertexType2', 'VertexType1' and 'VertexTypeAny' *in that order* connected by *any kind* of edges 'e1','e2' and 'e3'"

What's the equivalent of this using OrientDB and gremlin in java?

It seems like if I would want to start with :

```
for(Vertex a : orientGraph.getVerticesOfClass("VertexType2")){

}
```

and then start my gremlin code with vertex 'a' followed by a 'both' so that I spread out from vertex 'a' until I confirm / deny that a is connected in the way that I want.

In the end I want to have all the vertices and edges in Java so that I can do some adding / removing of edges and vertices, so I'd have:

```
OrientVertex a;
OrientVertex b;
OrientVertex c;
OrientVertex d;
OrientEdge e1;
OrientEdge e2;
OrientEdge e3;
```

Is this possible with gremlin in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the gremlin query you are looking for:

```
 g.V().has('@class', T.eq, 'VertexType1').as('b').bothE().as('e1').bothV().as('a').has('@class', T.eq, 'VertexType2').bothE().as('e2').bothV().as('c').has('@class', T.eq, 'VertexType1').bothE().as('e3').bothV().path
```

Comment: As an alternative, you can look at MATCH statement in OrientDB, it will be released in next minor release (2.2) https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-docs/blob/master/source/SQL-Match.md The syntax will be very similar to the original Cypher